# Send multiple data with jQuery.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send multiple data with jQuery.ajax. The combobox `product1` and the textbox `price` are working. But when I try to send the text of `quantity` something goes wrong.

**index.php**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM forms";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<select class='form-control select2' id='product1' onChange='getPrice(this.value)' name='product1' style='width: 100%;'>";
     echo "<option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                      echo "<option value='" . $row["id"]. "'>" . $row["naam"]. "</option>";
     }                   
echo "</select>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>
<html>
<body>
<!-- Your text input -->
<input id="quantity" type="text" placeholder="quantity">

<!-- Your text input -->
<input id="product_name" type="text" placeholder="product_name">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getPrice() {

    // getting the selected id in combo
    var selectedItem = jQuery('#product1 option:selected').val();

    // Do an Ajax request to retrieve the product price
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'get.php',
    method: 'POST',
data: 'id=' + selectedItem + ', quantity:document.getElementById('quantity').value,
    success: function(response){
        // and put the price in text field
        jQuery('#product_name').val(response);
        jQuery('#quantity').html(response);        },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    },
}); 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**get.php**

```
<?php

// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);

?>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) ;
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error) ;
    } 
else 
    {
    $product1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) ;
    $quantity = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'html', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) ;

    $query = 'SELECT price * ' . $quantity . ' FROM forms WHERE id=' . $product1 . ' ';

    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query) ;
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) 
{
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ;
    echo $result['price'];
}else{
    echo "0 results";
}

    }

?>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What goes wrong? "something" goes wrong is not descriptive enough to be helpful. post what your error / log / errorlog is.

Comment: I dont get any error. I try to run a SQL query: `SELECT price * ' . $quantity . ' FROM forms WHERE id=' . $product1 . '` but nothing is happening.

Comment: have you tried to check if your SQL query is forming correctly? by either debugging/ doing a print_r then exit.

Comment: Yes, I tried it in phpmyadmin and it is working there

Comment: The statement: `SELECT price * 2 FROM forms WHERE id=1` is working.

Comment: No you don't understand, do you know FOR SURE if your $quantity and $product1 is being set correctly so that your SQL statement is correctly formed?

Comment: `$product1` is working. I have no problem with `SELECT price FROM forms WHERE id=' . $product1 . ' ` in get.php. This statement is working. But now I need to send the variable `$quantity` to get.php. The problem is when I put `jQuery('#quantity').val(response);` under the working `jQuery('#product_name').val(response);` nothing is happening. I get the price but not the total price of a product (price * quantity = totalprice)

Comment: Do you want something like
data: {
id:selectedItem,
quantity:document.getElementById('quantity').value
},

Comment: Yes, thats what I want

Comment: Did it solved your issue?

Comment: No, I think i need to add more to `function getPrice() `. The `id:selectedItem` part is working. But I dont get any results when I put `quantity:document.getElementById('quantity').value },` in my code

Comment: Use firebug to check if ajax request is submiting the post data to php.

Comment: No, it is not posting anything. The code is submitting the post when I delete all off the `quantity` codes in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in index.php:

```
data: {'id': selectedItem, 'quantity' : jQuery('#quantity').val()},
```

and modify get.php.

```
$product1 = isset($_POST['id'])?$_POST['id']:'';
$quantity = isset($_POST['quantity'])?$_POST['quantity']:'';
$query = 'SELECT price * ' . $quantity . ' AS price FROM forms WHERE id=' . $product1 . ' ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
<input id="quantity" type="text" placeholder="quantity" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>">
<input id="product_name" type="text" placeholder="product_name" value="<?php echo $product_name; ?>">
```

In get.php and set its values by echo'ing it into the inputs.

Write the data to a div in index.php with

```
$("#yourdiv").html(response);
```

Comment: Not working. I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
(index):22 Uncaught ReferenceError: getPrice is not definedonchange @ (index):22` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: getPrice is not defined @ (index):1` in my developer tool console

Comment: You are using jquery wrong. You cant split the response the way you do

Comment: I can rewrite your code for you in about 6 hours. So if you can wait... give me the full code you have now and ill fix it for you tonight (timezone over here ECT)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what's going on there without any error messages, and I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Are you talking about it not working when you un-comment the last line here?

```
success: function(response){
    // and put the price in text field
    jQuery('#product_name').val(response);
    // jQuery('#quantity').val(response);
}
```

That line says to populate the quantity field with all the data that comes back from PHP.  Do you want to store the same value (response) in the product_name field and in the quantity field?  If you want to SEND the quantity to the PHP script, you need to include it's value in the DATA portion:

```
data: 'id=' + selectedItem + ', qty=' + $('#quantity').val(),
```

I would suggest sending back a JSON object with the values you want, and then put those values into the appropriate fields.

```
$array["qty"] = $row[i]["qty"];
$array["cost"] = $row[i]["cost"];

echo json_encode($array);
```

When you get the data back from PHP you can do something like this...

```
resultInfo = JSON.stringify(response);
jQuery('#product_cost').val(resultInfo["cost"]);
jQuery('#quantity').val(resultInfo["qty"]);
```

In PHP, make sure it's reading the qty as a number so SQL isn't trying to multiply (cost * '2') instead of (cost * 2).

```
$qty = (int)$_POST("qty"); //capture it as an integer
```

Depending on how secure you need this to be, it's worth mentioning that you may want to look into sanitizing your input.  I would suggest using PDO with prepared statments.

I hope something here may be able to help you.

Comment: The code is working without `quantity`. When I expend it with `quantity` and make calculations in sql `(see get.php in my first post)` nothing will happen. Also the things that worked before (like #product_name) are not working.

When I delete quantity. I can see the price of one individual product. When I want to calculate the total price (price * quantity = totalprice) nothing is happening in my script. I think that I post `quantity` in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code a little to

```
data:{ 
   id:selectedItem, 
   quantity:document.getElementById('quantity').value 
},
```

Comment: No, I still dont get a result. Is it possible that i need to add something like `var selectedItem = jQuery('#product1 option:selected').val();` for `quantity`. Or that `jQuery('#quantity').html(response);` in `index.php` or `$quantity = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'html', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) ;` in `get.php` is wrong?